# Sum of Values for Slider and Checkboxes (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, slider

I am trying to sum the values of elements on my page. They consist of Slider elements and Checkbox elements. My sliders have a class of ".valuez" and I am targeting my checkboxes with "input[type=checkbox]". The snippets below both work great separately, but I need them to function as one to ultimately give me the sum of all values on my page.

```js
$('.valuez').change(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('.valuez').each(function(){
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });

  $('li').html(sum);
});



$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });

  $('li').html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could break this out into functions:

```
$('.valuez').change(updateTotal);
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(updateTotal);


function sumSlider(){

  var sum = 0;
  $('.valuez').each(function(){
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });

  return sum;
}

function sumCheckbox(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });

  return sum;
}

function updateTotal(){
   $('li').html(sumSlider() + sumCheckbox());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select both `.valuez` and checkboxes like this :

```
$('input[type=checkbox], .valuez').change(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('input[type=checkbox], .valuez').each(function(){
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });

  $('li').html(sum);
});
```

Comment: I ended up going with this: `$("input[type=checkbox], .valuez").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked, .valuez").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("li").html(total);
});`